opa-sdk library decision api not returning output similar to rego playground
I use following code to get decision using opa/sdk in go lang.
code:
    import "github.com/open-policy-agent/opa/sdk"
    options := sdk.DecisionOptions{Path: decisionReq.Policy, Input: decisionReq.Input}
    decision, err := opa.Decision(ctx, options)

If i print decision it has a Result field which gives output as true or false.
but if you use a regoplayground it has a section called output and more output details are returned. I also want to have output similar to rego playground in opa sdk api what should be done?
example:
Refer following wiki
https://medium.com/@chathuragunasekera/implementing-policies-with-opa-example-use-cases-6f8f850cdec4
in "Use Case III" The output of rego playground is
{
    "action_is_read": true,
    "allow": true,
    "viewable_sensor_data": [
        [
            {
                "location": "Colombo",
                "precipitation": "1200 mm",
                "temperature": "30 C",
                "windspeed": "6.0 m/s"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "location": "Kandy",
                "precipitation": "800 mm",
                "temperature": "25 C",
                "windspeed": "4.5 m/s"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "location": "Sri Lanka",
                "precipitation": "1000 mm",
                "temperature": "28 C",
                "windspeed": "5.5 m/s"
            }
        ]
    ]
}

But in my code the decision output for same input and policy path app/abc/allow is just True or False.

The playground always evaluates the entire package you've put into it's Rego panel. Your SDK Decision call evaluates a certain path:
Path: decisionReq.Policy

If that path is not the path of the package, but, say, the path to your allow rule, you'd only see true/false.

Thanks for the response I gave path as package and I got the output but there is one difference. in rego-playground output doesn't contain entire data. but in the opa-sdk output it contains additional field sensor_data  and it contains entire data as shown below.                                                                                                                             example: Refer following wiki https://medium.com/@chathuragunasekera/implementing-policies-with-opa-example-use-cases-6f8f850cdec4   "Use Case III" .

{
"ID": "5c840894-f934-48ab-817e-9eaf853c75d9",
"Result": {
"action_is_read": true,
"allow": true,
"sensor_data": [
.... //entire data is coming
],
"viewable_sensor_data": [
...  // proper output
]
},
"Provenance": {
"version": "0.70.0",
"build_commit": "",
"build_timestamp": "",
"build_hostname": "",
"bundles": {
"opabundle": {
"revision": ""
}
}
}
}

What path do you query exactly? Also, how do you load the JSON data? I'm afraid there's a little too much guesswork here to give you any actionable advise...

I created direcroty structure as shown below  and placed policy.rego and data.json.
policies/sensor/policyy.rego ,polcies/data/data.json  .  build bundle  using command opa build --v1-compatible policies policies/data -o /tmp/bundle.tar.gz.

policy.rego  contents  refer the medium.com link above usecase III modified data.sensor_data to data.sensor.sensor_data   `package sensor \n
import rego.v1 \n
default allow := false
allow if { \n
viewable_sensor_data \n
action_is_read \n
} \n
action_is_read if "read" in input.actions \n
viewable_sensor_data contains view_data if { \n
some sensor_data in data.sensor.sensor_data  \n
sensor_data.timestamp >= input.time_period.from \n
sensor_data.timestamp < input.time_period.to \n
view_data := {datatype: sensor_data[datatype] | datatype in input.datatypes} \n
}` \n

decision process in go lang   log.Debugf("SDK making a decision") \n         options := sdk.DecisionOptions{Path: decisionReq.Policy, Input: decisionReq.Input} \n         decision, err := opa.Decision(ctx, options) \n         fmt.Printf("fmt output: %+v", decision) \n         log.Debugf(" opa Decision output") \n         jsonOutput, err := json.MarshalIndent(decision, "", "  ") \n     if err != nil {\n         log.Warnf("Error serializing decision output: %v", err) \n         return \n     }\n     log.Debugf("RAW opa Decision output:\n%s\n", string(jsonOutput))\n

The path I send is "path":"sensor"  sensor is the package name. I provide a configuration to sdk to load the bundle.tar.gz created above using a http server. let me know if you need more info. config {   "services": [     {       "name": "opa-bundle-server",       "url": "http://localhost:8282/opa/bundles"     }   ],   "bundles": {     "opabundle": {       "service": "opa-bundle-server",       "resource": "bundle.tar.gz"     }   } }

data.json file contains the data provided in the medium.com link above usecaseIII. let me know if you need more details.

Sorry for the radio silence. This is not the best venue for that type of problem, I think. Would it be possible for you to create an issue in the OPA repo, perhaps including a MWE?
